# GridvView FooterRow Total

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView with dynamically generated columns based on the user's query.
This means that sometimes I can have 1 column with xxx column name, or I can have up to 4 columns.

So: () means optional

```
AAA | (BBB) | (CCC) | (DDD)

 1      7       45      2
 22     9       6       33
...    ...     ...     ...
```

I need to sum up the totals of each of the columns without knowing which columns will be available until the program runs.

I'm trying to use the e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer portion of the GridView_RowDataBound event, but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to work.

I am saving the running totals in variables via the e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow portion of the event, but I can't seem to figure out how to "inject"  the saved items into the footer of the grid based on the available column(s).

Can anyone give me a bit of assistance?

*EDIT*

Gridview is done with basic mark up since the columns are built dynamically.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" nRowDataBound="gv_RowDataBound">
</asp:GridView>
```

And then the code for the columns:

```
private void BindGrid()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    var stt = from t in edcQuery.ToList()
                            where t.Technician.TeamId == 1
                            orderby t.RequestType.Name
                            select new
                            {
                                RequestType = t.RequestType.Name,
                                Tech = t.Technician.Name,
                            };
                    dt.Columns.Add("Support Ticket Type");
                    DataRow dr;
                    foreach (var col in stt.OrderBy(x => x.Tech).GroupBy(x => x.Tech))
                    {
                        dt.Columns.Add(col.Key.Substring(0, col.Key.IndexOf(' ')).Trim());
                    }
                    foreach (var type in stt.GroupBy(x => x.RequestType))
                    {
                        dr = dt.NewRow();
                        dr["Support Ticket Type"] = type.Key;
                        foreach (var tech in type.GroupBy(x => x.Tech))
                        {
                            dr[tech.Key.Substring(0, tech.Key.IndexOf(' ')).Trim()] = (object)tech.Count() == System.DBNull.Value ? 0 : tech.Count();
                        }
                        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                    }

                    //gvEDCSupportTicketType.FooterRow.Cells[2].Text = "0";
                    gvEDCSupportTicketType.DataSource = dt;
                    gvEDCSupportTicketType.DataBind();
}

double atot = 0.0;
double btot = 0.0;
double ctot = 0.0;
double dtot = 0.0;
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var dataRow = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;

        string[] columnNames = { "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD" };

    foreach (var item in columnNames)
        {
            var checkName = dataRow.Row.Table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Any(x => x.ColumnName.Equals(item, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

            if (checkName)
            {
                if (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, item) != DBNull.Value && Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, item)) != 0)
                {
                    switch (item)
                    {
                        case "AAA":
                            atot += Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, item));
                            break;
                        case "BBB":
                            btot += Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, item));
                            break;
                        case "CCC":
                            ctot += Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, item));
                            break;
                        case "DDD":
                            dtot += Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, item));
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "Totals:";
        e.Row.Cells[0].Attributes.Add("style", "text-align: right;");

    }
}
```

So as you can see, it builds the grid from a datatable and only uses the columns necessary at run time.  there is no static FooterTemplate or anything.

Comment: Can you post a bit of code?  The GridView definition and a sample binding would really help.

Comment: updated the code in the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use try catch for this like below.

```
      else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
{
    try
    {
    e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "Totals:" + atot.ToString();
    e.Row.Cells[0].Attributes.Add("style", "text-align: right;");
    }
    catch
    {
    }
    try
    {
    e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "Totals:" + btot.ToString();
    e.Row.Cells[1].Attributes.Add("style", "text-align: right;");
    }
    catch
    {
    }
    try
    {
    e.Row.Cells[2].Text = "Totals:" + ctot.ToString();
    e.Row.Cells[2].Attributes.Add("style", "text-align: right;");
    }
    catch
    {
    }
    try
    {
    e.Row.Cells[3].Text = "Totals:" + dtot.ToString();
    e.Row.Cells[3].Attributes.Add("style", "text-align: right;");
    }
    catch
    {
    }

}
```

**OR**

```
        else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
        {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (TableCell c in e.Row.Cells)
        {
            switch (i)
            {
                case 0:
                    c.Text = "Totals:" + atot.ToString();
                    c.Attributes.Add("style", "text-align: right;");
                    break;
                case 1:
                     c.Text = "Totals:" + btot.ToString();
                    c.Attributes.Add("style", "text-align: right;");
                    break;
                case 2:
                     c.Text = "Totals:" + ctot.ToString();
                    c.Attributes.Add("style", "text-align: right;");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    c.Text = "Totals:" + dtot.ToString();
                    c.Attributes.Add("style", "text-align: right;");
                    break;
            }
            i++;
        }
        }
```

So if there is footer cell available , it will go through otherwise go to catch part.

Comment: The only issue with this is that BBB may not always be in the correct index position.  Sometimes, that could be CCC or even DDD.

The only one that will always be in the correct place would be AAA.  So for instance, I could have this:

AAA - CCC
or
AAA - BBB - DDD

but I can also have
BBB - CCC
or
BBB - DDD

You know what I mean?  Not all columns are always going to be used, since they're dynamic based on the query.  Therefore, I don't know the index at design time.

Comment: So simple solution is instead of checking which column name it is and saving it, just save it with column1, column2, column3 So when you will get it back it will be in same order as you save it.

Comment: I actually got this to work by adding a simple loop before the grid databind and manually adding BoundFields.  But since you were basically leading me down the right path and i implemented a similar method to what you stated in your edit, your answer will be acceptable.